# Trouble with message character encoding in Amazon SQS messages

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-sqs

I have a rather puzzling problem with Amazon SQS and Zend(1.11.2).  I am sending a message to the queue that I have setup with a snip-it that looks like this:

```
$sqs->send($queueURL, "opt1=foo opt2=bar");
```

The message comes in to the app at the far side and is seen as:

```
"opt1%3Dfoo+opt2%3Dbar"
```

The receiving app is written in Java using the com.xerox.amazonws.sqs2 library and is in production now.

There was similar sending code in an older php module that used Tarzan under Drupal that worked just fine.  I have searched high and low and read the documentation for Zend, Amazon and the Java library and I am stuck.

The encoding of the string is understandable but I don't recognize the method being used.  Further tests show that single quotes, angle brackets, etc. are also escaped as hex.

Any ideas?

Ken

Comment: A bit more information.  Zend is urlencoding outbound messages and urldecoding inbound messages.  It appears from what I am seeing that the Java Typica library is not doing a urldecode.  It also appears that the Tarzan PHP library is not doing the ulrencoding either.  I must be missing how interoperability works with these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

[Typica](http://code.google.com/p/typica/) (com.xerox.amazonaws) has a '[encoded](http://typica.s3.amazonaws.com/com/xerox/amazonws/sqs2/MessageQueue.html#isEncoding%28%29)' option that internally uses Base64 to encode messages. This is on by default.

In general, we have found that encoding messages using Base64 is less troublesome then URL/percent encoding when using SQS.

I would Base64 the message text in PHP, write it to the queue, and Typica should decode just fine using the default config.

Comment: This is great but toolkits like the Zend Framework do a URL encode on the message before it is sent and a URL decode on the received message.  This behavior is not optional.  It appears that clients and servers need to be a matched set to work.  Base64 or URL encoding are both fine options but they don't interoperate.  - Ken

Comment: @Ken Base64 encoding/decoding in Typica is optional. When setting up the MessageQueue call q.setEncoding(false) and do the decoding yourself after reading the message.